# How to configure spring-social-facebook for a facebook canvas application

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

Looking at [Keith Donald's](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart) and [Roger Hughes's](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/getting-started-with-spring-social-part.html) spring tutorial, the flow is as follows;

```
IF user is signed in to to application THEN 
    IF user is signed in to Facebook
        read Facebook data, 
        display Facebook data
    ELSE (facebook handles) 
        ask user to loging to Facebook
        goto if user is signed in to Facebook step
    ENDIF
ELSE 
    ask user to sign in
    create user object with an id 
    when user has signed in, go back to the beginning
END IF
```

However as my application is going to run on a facebook canvas I want to skip the sign-in to application stage (as it is meaningless to as the user to login explicitly to my application which already is running on facebook) for which the flow is going to be something like;

```
    create a user (session scope)
    IF user is signed in to Facebook
        update user object with facebook id
        read Facebook data, 
        display Facebook data
    ELSE (facebook handles) 
        ask user to loging to Facebook
        goto if user is signed in to Facebook step
    ENDIF
```

Would really appreciate a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that there is a sample on [gitspring-social-samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-canvas/) specifically for canvas usage.